# Looping nested Json data in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

In my mockdata I was able to loop through some data for the most part.
When you get to students within upcoming you can see that I nested some data.
The issue I am having is being able to print that nested data.

```
{
  "upcoming": [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "Feb 2nd, 2018",
    "time": "2 to 4pm",
    "status":"$45",
    "course": "Oil Painting",
    "course_type": "(Individual)",
    "student":[
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "date": "Feb 2nd, 2018",
    "time": "2 to 4pm",
    "status":"$45",
    "course": "Oil Painting",
    "course_type": "(Group)",
    "student":[
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "date": "Feb 2nd, 2018",
    "time": "2 to 4pm",
    "status":"$45",
    "course": "Oil Painting",
    "course_type": "(Group)",
    "student":[
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      }
    ]
  }],
  "future":[{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "Feb 2nd, 2018",
    "time": "2 to 4pm",
    "status":"$45",
    "course": "Oil Painting",
    "course_type": "(Group)",
    "student":[
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Perkins",
        "image": "/img/student-icon.png"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

I am able to print the date, status, and course into my ejs template, but when I try to display the students images I get an error saying it is undefined.

```
<% data.upcoming.forEach((record) => { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=record.date%>
          <span style="display: block;font-size:10pt;">3 to 4pm</span>
      </td>
      <td>Recieved
        <span style="display:block; font-size: 16pt; color:#7c0000;"><%=record.status%></span>
      </td>
      <td><%=record.course%>
        <span style="display:block;font-size:10pt;"><%=record.course_type%></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        LOOK HERE
        <% data.upcoming.student.forEach((person) => { %>
          <img rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ann Perkins" src="<%=person.image%>">
        <% }) %>
      </td>
    <% }) %>
```

Am I using the right method to get the array of objects within students?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `data.upcoming.student.forEach((person) => {` with `record.student.forEach(...)`

The student array lies within the array that you are looping above in the ejs template's first line

Comment: Thank you for noticing. I did not see that whatsoever